# How can I execute continue after break in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am a begginer to javascript. I was writing some code for my program in which mainly it's loop. It's about you enter your age and it says you should drive or not a simple program but , I wanted to make it repeating itself until the user didn't enters n or N. I wrote a if statement with break and another else - if statement with continue. When i press n it stops but , when I type y it dosen't continue. Plz try to help me Here is the code below:

```
while(true){
  let age = prompt("Enter your age")
  if (age>18){
    console.log("You can drive")
  }
 
  else if (age<0){
    console.log("Invalid age")
  }
  else if (age>100){
    console.log("Invalid age")
  }
  
  else if (age==18){
    console.log("Come to our office")
  }
  else{
    console.log("You cannot drive")
  }
  
  let choice = prompt("Type y or Y to run again type n or N to exit")
  
  if(choice == "n" || "N"){
    continue
  }

  if (choice == "y" || "Y")
    break
}
```

Comment: `continue` starts the loop again from the beginning - `break` exits the loop. You have them backward!

Answer (score 2):

Your if conditions are strange, you say `if(choice == "n" || "N")`, which means, in words "go in the next block if the variabe choice is 'n' or if 'N'". I'm guessing saying `if("N")` gets interpreted as true, since it's not null.

You should write, explicitly, `if(choice === "n" || choice === "N")`.

Also, as phuzi said in the comments, `continue` makes the code restart the loop with the next iteration, while `break` makes the code go out of the loop. It seems you have them backwards